# Has Marvel provided and explanation of lightning not affecting some Marvel characters?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, storm

So ignoring the likes of Storm, Electro, and Thor because they have some form of "control" over the element, there are times when those characters use lightning on other high level characters and the receiver is (virtually) unaffected. Let's say Thor shocking Thanos, though it presumably happened off screen in IW.

Has Marvel provided a somewhat science based explanation of how bipedal, humanoid creatures would be able to stand the effects of lightning surging through their bodies? Something to do with muscle density perhaps, or maybe water content, or possibly not even being carbon based life forms?

Comment: I believe questions asking for scientific explanations of things are off-topic here, but this looks like a perfectly valid question for WorldBuilding.SE. Try asking over there.

Comment: In theory a life-form using a non-conductive compound as a liquid solvent, in place of water, might do okay. Pure liquid ammonia would be an example, however, a being that required pure liquid ammonia would have far more pressing issues than lightning to worry about in an Earth-like environment.

Comment: @F1Krazy I believe this may be on-topic, or could be made on-topic, based on the general consensus here:
https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-is-our-actual-policy-on-science-questions

Comment: It would be on topic to ask if the MCU ever provided a psuedo-scientific explanation for tge abilities.

Comment: Would it be more on topic if I asked "if any Marvel material has attempted to provide a science based explanation"?

Comment: @SteveEggering yes, putting it in terms of what evidence Marvel has provided (explicitly or implicitly, in-universe or out-of-universe (e.g. interviews)) would make this on-topic IMO.

Comment: One might also ask whether Marvel has provided a science based explanation to anything. :) Saying that Thor's blood is made of ammonia and that he's ten times as dense as mere mortals isn't just clearly incorrect, it wouldn't even really explain anything.

Comment: @Zabeus - Pseudo of course being the operative word.

Answer (score 1):

With Thanos it’s mostly just the fact he’s extremely durable, he’s likely one of the most durable characters in Marvel. He’s fought the Hulk, Drax the Destroyer (while Drax had the power gem). Has been hit by Galactus' cosmic blasts, etc. All with little to no damage, he’s even fought against Odin and was relatively fine even though Odin won.

Comment: Right but what exactly does durable mean? I can punch my fist into water all day and the water doesn't change, does that make water durable? I can apply electrolysis using table salt and a battery and the water breaks down at a molecular level, doesn't seem so durable now.

Comment: It means that if you hit him really hard or electrocute him, not much happens. Why? Because of his magical super strength.